# WSO2 box_carring of Data Service Hosting feature 4.3.4 doesn't work in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am having problem to use DSS as a feature when installed to ESB.

I installed "Data Service Hosting" version 4.3.4 from repository 
http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/wilkes/

The ESB version to test is version 4.9.0

I have set up a testing dataservice with box carring.
I try to call “begin_boxcar” to dataservice to following endpoint
http://localhost:9763/services/orderDS/

But there is no cookie information return from service.

I also verify the response by using SoapUI.

Please help.

Comment: The same data service configuration work with a DSS?

Comment: This looks like it is a bug. In DSS 3.5.0 there's a new feature called request_box, which you may be able to use in place of box carring. Please see https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS350/Step+1%3A+Defining+the+Data+Service#Step1:DefiningtheDataService-Enableboxcarring/requestbox for more details. There should be a new operation called request box, which you can use to combine a set of operations in one service call and it should commit only if all operations are successful. Your other option is to use external DSS.